# Type Mismatch vba overdue date highlighter

Tags: vba, excel

Still not great at VBA...

```
Sub CompareDates()

Dim dueDate As Date, sht As Worksheet, i As Long

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

For i = 1 To CountMyRows(sht.Name)
    dueDate = CDate(sht.Range("E" & i))
    If dueDate > Date Then
        sht.Range("E" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    End If
Next i

Next sht

End Sub
```

getting type mismatch on this:

```
dueDate = CDate(sht.Range("E" & i))
```

I have no idea why this is not working at I have someone else testing it and it works on theirs.

EDIT: I have got rid of the error BUT the code doesn't work and highlight all the overdue tasks...

Comment: What is the value of `sht.Range("E" & i)`

Comment: I have a feeling that particular cell has a formula error like `#DIV/0!` or `#NA` or something similar

Comment: @SiddharthRout hey again! it was supposed to be column 5 as I want the macro to search every column in E column on every sheet

Comment: I know you are looping through col 5 but when you get the error, debug it and see what the value of `sht.Range("E" & i)` is

Comment: When I hover over it says c_date= "due date"

Comment: If you have headers like `name`, `thing`, `stuff`, `due date` then start the loop from row 2 where the actual dates are `For i = 2 to CountMyRows(sht.Name)`

Comment: Oh yeah! thanks for pointing that out!! @RobinMackenzie

Comment: See my answer below to avoid other errors by using the `IsDate` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IsDate` before you use `CDate` to prevent the error. `CDate` only works if you pass in a value that can actually be converted to a date.

You can change your code to this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareDates()

    Dim dueDate As Date, sht As Worksheet, i As Long

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        For i = 1 To CountMyRows(sht.Name)
            If IsDate(sht.Range("E" & i).Value) Then '<-- check if value is a date
                dueDate = CDate(sht.Range("E" & i))
                If dueDate > Date Then
                    sht.Range("E" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
                End If
            End If
        Next i

    Next sht

End Sub
```

Example - note it won't work for something like 13th July 2017:

[image]

Comment: Hiya @RobinMackenzie Thanks for this but its still not highlighting the overdue dates

Answer (score 0):

Does it fail each time in the 'For' loop ?

```
dueDate = CDate(sht.Range("E" & i))
```

will fail when `sht.Range("E" & i))` will return a text for example.

Try to first assign `sht.Range("E" & i))` to a variable like:

```
For i = 1 To 5

    c_date = sht.Range("E" & i)
    dueDate = CDate(c_date)
    If dueDate > Date Then
        sht.Range("E" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    End If
Next I
```

so you can better track the progress - maybe your underlying data is not valid for such comparison (it's not a date)

Comment: Hey! Its still saying type mismatch. for 
dueDate= CDate(c_date) @SławomirMytych